# close open submenu when hover over another menu

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu with a sub menu inside. When you hover over the main menu the sub menu opens. when you click on the sub menu the submenu stays open because it is given the 'on' class. What I want is if the user hovers over another main menu section the submenu close on the below one and open on the one they are hovering.

```
 <div class="sideMenu2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href>retail</a>
             <ul class="subsideMenu2">
               <li><a href="/portfolio/8/0">the elements</a></li>
               <li><a href="/portfolio/9/0">bullring</a></li>
               <li><a href="/portfolio/10/0">braehead</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li ><a href class="on">sports &amp; leisure</a>
               <ul class="subsideMenu2">
                      <li class= "on"><a href="/portfolio/19/0">the rose bowl</a></li>
                           <li><a href="/portfolio/48/0">alton towers pool</a></li>
               </ul>
        </li></ul>
```

CSS:

```
.sideMenu ul li.on a
{
    height:2em;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background:url(../images/point.png) no-repeat;
    font-weight:bold;   
}

.sideMenu ul
{    
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;  
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:1em;
    width:20em;
    color:#fff;   
    margin-left:-10px;
}

.sideMenu ul a{
    padding: 2px 20px 0px 0px;  
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    width:19.2em;
}

.sideMenu li a
{
    height:2em;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left:15px;
}

.sideMenu li a:hover{
    background:url(../images/point.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer; 
    padding-left:-15px;
}

.sideMenu h4{
    display:none;
}

.sideMenu2 ul li.on a
{
    height:2em;
    padding-top: 2px;   
/** font-weight:bold;   **/
}

a.on 
{    
   background:url(../images/point.png) no-repeat;
}

.sideMenu2 ul
{    
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;  
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:1.1em;

    color:#fff;   
    margin-left:-10px;
}

.sideMenu2 ul a{
    padding: 2px 20px 0px 0px;  
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    width:16.6em;
}

.sideMenu2 li a
{
    height:2em;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left:15px;
}

.sideMenu2 li a:hover{
    background:url(../images/point.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer; 
    padding-left:-15px;

}

.sideMenu2 ul ul
{    
    display:none;
}
.sideMenu2 li:hover .subsideMenu2 {
  display: block;
}

.sideMenu2 li .subsideMenu2 {
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 20px;   
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:0.8em;
    width:20em;
    color:#fff;   
    margin-left:-10px; 
}

.sideMenu2 li .subsideMenu2 li.on a
{
    height:2em;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background:url(../images/point.png) no-repeat;
/** font-weight:bold;**/    
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/LSZBg/9/

Comment: How are you achieving the effect? Via CSS or Jquery? Provide us with the code that does the hover effect you speak of so we can better provide you with an answer that can help, as theres several ways to do rollover/hover effects with various methods of CSS and or Jquery or combination of both.

Comment: Consider using jsfiddle.net when asking your question. It really helps people create a working solution fast.

Comment: code up what you have in jsfiddle that'll give us something to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your menu items are given a class. Instead of using `.sideMenu ul li`, just use `li.main_menu_item` or something:

```
$(function() {
   $('li.main_menu_item').hover(function() {
      // Hide all open sub-menus
      $('li.main_menu_item').removeClass('on');

      // Show only this menu item's sub-menu
      $(this).addClass('on');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can bind the hover event with a function that loops on all the items that have the "on" class and remove it with jquery and you can set the current hover item using "this" object to set it's item to "on", if you posted the javascript you used to do this menu, i can help you do that, or you can put the code sample on fiddler

Comment: i used css, and also then if the user goes off the hover that means the on class needs to be re-binded to what ti was taken off from?

Comment: sorry, i don't know the meaning of your question